# how to upload the worker role on windows azure

Tags: azure

I have a solution which includes two projects:

1. A Windows Azure cloud service;
2. A worker role.

The workerRole project only uses a thread to do something.

I want to publish this project to my Windows Azure.

But when I finish it, the worker role works, but the thread may not work.

For example, I write some code that sends a email to my mailbox every 10 minutes. When I run it locally, it works, I can receive mail. But if I publish to Azure, I can't receive the mail.

How do I publish my worker role to Azure and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worker role is published with any other roles directly from Visual Studio (or the command line if you prefer). If your role is definitely running (and not showing an error in the dashboard when it tries to start) then there is something wrong with your code.

You need to check that what you are doing with your email sending code is valid. Is something blocking the Azure IP but allowing your local IP? I send emails from a worker role and it works fine in Azure using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient and relaying via GMail.